# Fresh install (20.04) on NUC10 but no HDMI audio, only 'dummy output'

Tags: sound, hdmi, output, intel-nuc

**Problem**

After a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 (as well as LinuxMint 20.2 Cinnamon and Elementary Os 6) Intel NUC10I7FNHN, I do not have the option to select the HDMI sound output in the sound settings, only `dummy` as sound output.

The system is dual boot - from Windows I am able to play sound over HDMI, which ruled out issues with the different hardware components (TV, HDMI cable and port).

**Things i tried to do**

1. The frequent solutions

   - Reinstalling `pulseaudio` and `alsa` packages.
   - `pulseaudio -k`, nothing.
   - `pacmd list-sinks` only shows the dummy sink profile.
   - `aplay -l` returns no results.
2. Upgraded to the latest NUC10 BIOS(0053).
3. I tried following both fixes from [Logix's Fix No Sound (Dummy Output) Issue In Ubuntu With SND HDA Intel](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html)
   :

   - Editing `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` by adding `options snd-hda-intel model=generic` at the end.
   - Editing same file with `options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0` and `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` with `blacklist snd_soc_skl` at the end.
4. Debug the with the `alsa-info` tool [Generated output](http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=998e4ee5560e9f00052071afe48981b46a5524c8)

Comment: LM and Elementary both have their own support venues. It is not a good idea to lump all you can in a pile and dump it here.

Comment: Thanks @mikewhatever! I agree, I mentioned them mainly so people looking up that same problem as I did this past week might stumble upon this post.

Comment: Since all of the mentioned OS s have the issue I would say hardware problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution for my problem, posting here so it might help others save some time.

**TL;DR**

Upgraded kernel to `5.14+`, as a fix has been applied for the NUC10.

**Underlying problem**

Found this [Github issue in clearlinux](https://github.com/clearlinux/distribution/issues/2396) related to the NUC10 and had a similar problem.
Noticed they have a similar `alsa-info` [output](https://github.com/clearlinux/distribution/issues/2396#issuecomment-872778658).
They had a patch made and merged to `alsa-devel` and to the kernel `5.14`.
The three OS's i tried had kernel version of `5.10` or `5.11`. (ElementaryOs 6, LM 20.02 and Ubuntu 20.04)

And indeed - installing the new kernel solved my problem!
This might also be solved with installing that specific `alsa` package, but I have not tried that.